# Postgres DB goes into read only mode during load testing

Tags: postgresql, jdbc

During the load testing - we have observed that the Postgres databases are going to read only mode for a brief amount of time and getting recovered within minutes.

could any one suggest what is happening here?

The below is the exception observed in the application when Postgres DB is going into read only mode.

> could not execute statement; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute statement
> Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: cannot execute UPDATE in a read-only transaction

Comment: Looks like an issue in your database connection, the JDBC settings. That’s where you have the option to select read only

Comment: It's not "the database" that's read only. For some reason your _connection_ was set to read only. e.g. by running `set transaction read only` or calling `Connection.setReadOnly(true)`  - it's somewhere in your Java code.